# filter in jquery to show only firstname td value

Tags: javascript, jquery

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#myInput").on("keyup", function() {
    var value = $(this).val().toLowerCase();
    $("#myTable tr").parent().siblings(":first").filter(function() {
      $(this).toggle($(this).text().toLowerCase().indexOf(value) > -1)
    });
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h2>Filterable Table</h2>

<input id="myInput" type="text" placeholder="Search..">
<br><br>

<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Firstname</th>
      <th>Lastname</th>
      <th>Email</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody id="myTable">
    <tr>
      <td>John</td>
      <td>Doe</td>
      <td>john@example.com</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Mary</td>
      <td>Moe</td>
      <td>mary@mail.com</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>July</td>
      <td>Dooley</td>
      <td>july@greatstuff.com</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Anja</td>
      <td>Ravendale</td>
      <td>a_r@test.com</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Trying to Type something in the input field to search the table for first names

Filtering firstname's td to show only first name matches value into the table. I tried but does not work pls guide

Also explain what's wrong in my code 
thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to search in the FirstName only. Use can use the following code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#myInput").on("keyup", function() {
    var value = $(this).val().toLowerCase();
    $("#myTable tr").filter(function() {
      $(this).toggle($(this).find("td:first").text().toLowerCase().indexOf(value) > -1)
    });
  });
});
```

Remove `.parent().siblings(":first")` and add `.find("td:first")` to search for the first td in each row, aka firstname

**Demo**

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#myInput").on("keyup", function() {
    var value = $(this).val().toLowerCase();
    $("#myTable tr").filter(function() {
      $(this).toggle($(this).find("td:first").text().toLowerCase().indexOf(value) > -1)
    });
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h2>Filterable Table</h2>

<input id="myInput" type="text" placeholder="Search..">
<br><br>

<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Firstname</th>
      <th>Lastname</th>
      <th>Email</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody id="myTable">
    <tr>
      <td>John</td>
      <td>Doe</td>
      <td>john@example.com</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Mary</td>
      <td>Moe</td>
      <td>mary@mail.com</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>July</td>
      <td>Dooley</td>
      <td>july@greatstuff.com</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Anja</td>
      <td>Ravendale</td>
      <td>a_r@test.com</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: @Alax No problem, happy to help